# Using javascript to show a grey-scale version of an image on mouse-over. in firefox its possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function ()  {
  var area = document.getElementById('area');
  alert('area:'+area);   
  var context = area.getContext('2d');
  alert('context:'+context);
  if (context) {
    var imgd = context.getImageData(0, 0, 500, 300);
    var pix = imgd.data;
    for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
      var grayscale = pix[i  ] * .3 + pix[i+1] * .59 + pix[i+2] * .11;
      pix[i]   = grayscale;   // red
      pix[i+1] = grayscale;   // green
      pix[i+2] = grayscale;   // blue
    }
    context.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);
  }
};
</script>
 </head>
  <body>
   <canvas id="area" width="500" height="300">
     <img id="canvasSource" src="http://www.treehugger.com/elephant-national-heritage-animal-india.jpg" alt="Canvas Source" />
   </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would for sure not use HTML4 doctype in an HTML5 page. And what error???

Comment: var imgd = context.getImageData(0, 0, 500, 300); in this line     Error: 'context' is undefined

Comment: still its showing
Line: 11
Error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Comment: THIS is an [HTML 5 doctype](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/): `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2d in lowercase and move the script inside the head tags

area.getContext('2d');

HERE is some code that might work better: http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsCanvasGrayscale/index.html

Here is my test html - I do not see an image yet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function ()  {
  var area = document.getElementById('area');
  alert('area:'+area);   
  var context = area.getContext('2d');
  alert('context:'+context)
  if (context) {
    var imgd = context.getImageData(0, 0, 500, 300);
    var pix = imgd.data;
    for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
      var grayscale = pix[i  ] * .3 + pix[i+1] * .59 + pix[i+2] * .11;
      pix[i]   = grayscale;   // red
      pix[i+1] = grayscale;   // green
      pix[i+2] = grayscale;   // blue
    }
    context.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);
  }
};
</script>
 </head>
  <body>
   <canvas id="area" width="500" height="300">
     <img id="canvasSource" src="http://www.treehugger.com/elephant-national-heritage-animal-india.jpg" alt="Canvas Source" />
   </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: alert: area:[object]                                                 Line: 9
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: I do not get an error. I get area: [object htmlcanvaselement] and then context:[object canvaserenderingcontext2d] in Fx7 on OSX - but I also do not get the image

Answer (score 1):

First, this won't work because you haven't defined context, put this at the start of your code:

```
var context = document.getElementById('area').getContext('2D');
```

Second, I don't think you should put an HTML4 doctype when using HTML5.

And third, here is a great tutorial for editing images using canvas, one of the examples is gray-scaling the image: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/

**Edit:** I forgot something, you want your code to run only after the page has loaded, so you need to put your code in the `window.onload` event, like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    //your code
};
```

Comment: still its showing
Line: 11
Error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Comment: Line: 13
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: @Aravinth If the answer does not help you, why do you accept it as answer?

Comment: i must want to implement in today itself...  i used many technics but no result...

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also do this without any JavaScript at all using SVG filters and a :hover style.

Edit: see http://people.mozilla.org/~roc/filter.xhtml the `id="f2"` filter and adjust the matrix as desired.

Comment: Would this not be a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: The question was about how to show a grey-scale version of an image on mouseover.  One of the ways to do that is using a SVG filter and a :hover style...  Dunno whether saying that counts as an answer, of course

Comment: Without a link to how or an example, I would call this a comment